# How to use the existing schema of mongoose of one project in another project?

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose

Suppose I have an existing project on student records in which I have a collection named student.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const studentSchema = mongoose.Schema({
name,
email,
});

mongoose.model('student', studentSchema);
```

Now I am working on new on new project of teacher details in which I want all the details of students too. so for this what I want is that to use the same database url which I used in the student records project for the connection and use the existing schema of student by the same name without creating its copy. But I don't know how to do this. So, can you please help me. I will be very much thankful for you.

note:- both the project are located on different locations and will be host on different servers.

Comment: did you find an answer for this?

Comment: no, I didn't find the answer, but for this, i defined all the schemas in every project where i want to user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not specifically a mongodb/mongoose question as you're looking for a way to share a datamodel between 2 projects.

If you're using `git` you can use `git submodules`, simply move the shared models to a new repository. Then include this repo in both existing projects with `git submodule add [repo]`

Another option would be to create an npm-package.

Comment: use of git submodules here is a great idea. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not a fan of git submodules (as they don't automatically keep themselves up-to-date), another alternative is to use a monorepo.  I'm using npm workspaces for the very purpose of sharing mongoose schemas between 2 apps.